# Flutter equivalent of layout_gravity="bottom"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to render a [dribbble sample](https://dribbble.com/shots/3514000--Calculator-UI-Challenge).

In normal android using XML, I can make any part stick to any side of another view. If I were using `ConstraintLayout`, I could make the bottom part stick to the bottom of the parent and let the top part expand to available height.

[image: dribbble sample]

The design on both emulators is `Flutter` code.
On larger screens, there is some empty space on the bottom. How do I remove that?

Currently, I am using `Flexible` with flex values but it doesn't look right. How to make this reactive?. Is the use of `Flexible` correct?

The code can found [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Kf05pPeC)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing like `android:layout_gravity` in Flutter, however you can pretty much achieve anything in Flutter. So, here you can use use `Spacer()`. Like:

```
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Spacer(),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text("123")),
    YourButtonsWidget(),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change CalculatorPrototype's build function like this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // actually this line and the next one doesn't needed
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: display,
          ),
          Container(
            child: keypad,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers. The answer by CopsOnRoad solves the problem in a generic way. Thank you very much. Upvoting your answer.